# how to get another element of same parent in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<name><last-name>aaa</last-name><first-name>bbb</first-name></name>
```

template is:

```
<xsl:template match="last-name">
  display first-name
</xsl:template>
```

How to do this?

Comment: There's a typo in your <first-name> node. SO edit rules don't allow me to fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../first-name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this input...

```
<name>
  <last-name>aaa</last-name>
  <first-name>bbb</first-name>
</name>
```

this stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="first-name" />

<xsl:template match="last-name">
  <xsl:comment>for last-name of <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:comment>
  <first-name>
   <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*" />      
  </first-name>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... produces ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--for last-name of aaa--><first-name>bbb</first-name>
```

Comment: Also, if you can't rely on the relative positions of first-name and last-name within name, then as an alternative to <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*" />, you can use ...
<xsl:value-of select="parent::*/first-name" />